# Tier Pricing import/export

Tags: magento2, importexport, tierprice, tiered-pricing

Very new to Magento and need some guidance.

We are running a promotion and need to remove tiered pricing however we want to re activate it after the promotion.

Is there a way I can export all products (inc tier pricing info), make a copy of the csv, delete tiered pricing info in the csv copy, then re-import/update the original csv after the promotion?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 provides Dataflow for importing/exporting Tier pricing by default.
But it has to be imported separately.

If you want to update regular price along with special, tier & customer group price, you can use this extension for Magento 2:
[Magento 2 Regular, Special & Tier Price Importer](https://www.magepsycho.com/magento2-mass-regular-special-tier-group-price-importer.html)